# Nativescript memory allocation increasing when navigate from page to page

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I run the Nativescript code from https://github.com/NativeScript/tutorials/tree/main/angular-tutorial.  I found that the memory allocation is increasing when I navigate from home page to detail page then navigate back from detail pages to home page multiple times. Would like to get your suggestions or idea how to stop memory allocation increasing since it will run out of memory at some point. Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: We have a similar issue after upgrading Nativescript. The app has several navigation issues on 4GB memory iphones. But if official sample tutorial code has a memory leak, no wonder our app has it too. Wondering how nobody found it yet.

Comment: The author upgraded the Angular version to 14.0.0 and that solved the problem for this repo. However similar problem still exists with RadList even with Angular 14.0.0. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72878325/memory-allocation-keeps-increasing-in-nativescript-radlistview