# Memory allocation keeps increasing in Nativescript RadListView

Tags: nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I am having a simple app with RadListView component as in https://github.com/banchasf/nativescript-radlistview-sample.  When I navigate to the page contains RadListView and navigate out to another page, the allocated memory is not freed from iOS device. Even though the leak is not indicated but the memory allocation keeps increasing when I revisit the RadListView page. It can be observed from the item “VM: TKListViewCellBackgroundView (CALayer)” in the allocation’s category in the attachment.  Would like to get your suggestions or idea how to free the memory. Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: No. it's not duplicate. This one is specific to RadListView component of Nativescript. The previous one with Angular Tutorial is resolved by the author now. Please check my comment on the other issue. This one is not resolved yet. I am not aware of a solution as of now.

Comment: @SackySan The author of what?

Comment: @SackySan, did you mean the author of the question, the OP?

Comment: Author of the Official Nativescript Angular Tutorial Repository.

Comment: This a bug specific to some library, then it should be reported not posted as a question on SO

Comment: Thanks @Vega for your suggestion. I will also post as an issue in the Nativescript git repository. I posted here because I thought some developers might discover this problem before and have a workaround that they might be able to share with us.